# Quasar with prerender-spa-plugin Unable to prerender all routes

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar-framework, prerender, pre-rendering

I have an error when I want to use 'prerender-spa-plugin' in my quasar application.

```
 App •  WAIT  • Compiling of "UI" in progress...
[prerender-spa-plugin] Unable to prerender all routes!
 App •  DONE  • "UI" compiled with errors • 8092ms

 App •  ERROR  •  UI  

[prerender-spa-plugin] Unable to prerender all routes!


 App •  COMPILATION FAILED  • Please check the log above for details.
```

I added `prerender-spa-plugin` in my `package.js`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.12.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "quasar": "^2.3.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.9",
    "vuex": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@quasar/app": "^3.2.1",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-qoverlay": "2.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "prerender-spa-plugin": "^3.4.0"
  },
```

I am trying to use it like this in the `quasar.conf.js`

I import it like this:

```
const path = require('path')
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')
```

```
build: {
  vueRouterMode: 'history', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
  extendWebpack (cfg) {
    cfg.plugins.push(
      new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
        staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/spa/'),
        routes: ['/', '/page1']
      })
    )
  },
...
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

I tried many things that I could find on google but without success.

Comment: This is just a hunch, but you might try changing the value of `staticDir` to `path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'spa')`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHorn , I tried but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You must turn on ssr mode to get pre-output with quasar

Comment: Hello, I tested the SSR mode but it is necessary to be able to launch the command indicated in the documentation here: 'https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-ssr/deploying '. I deploy on Netlify (to my knowledge this is not possible on Netlify)

Comment: use serverless in netlify